# Reading from a text file with unknown formatting

Tags: c, regex, file-io, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read from a text file. this text file does not have a specific pattern but is a paragraph of a story. I am trying to get each individual word and track their number of occurrences.

For example, this is a exerpt from the text file to give an idea of the formatting.

> In submitting the following record we are conscious of the fact that we have errors. Some of them have been found and 
>   corrected by pen even after the stencil had been out. Others, I presume will be found by you. Others will not be 
>   found, there are none among us today who have lived long enough in the past to know them. It is our sincere desire 
>   to make this record as accurate as possible. To do this we must have your help. If you fin a mistake kindly notify 
>   this writer who will in turn correct his copy. It is our intention to rewrite this story, making it more readable by 
>   including such personal human interest stories as are available; more accurate by correcting the mistakes which you 
>   may find. The first three pages are taken directly without any changes form the family record as written by cousin 
>   Ethel Mards Carr Marsh.  We are deeply indebted to here for this information. Without her help it would have been 
>   impossible to have gone back beyond the parents of Daniel and David. As stated in the history, four Marsh brothers 
>   came to the colonies some time prior to 1761. How many years before this date it was, we do not know. Samuel Marsh, 
>   Son of Zebediah Marsh, was born in 1761. We may well imagine that it was several years before his birth. We have 
>   studied the records of England of their period.  They were perilous years. Many came to America to escape the wrath 
>   of a tyrant Marsh King, others to escape the judgement of the Puritan Cromwell.

I know how to read from a file that is of a specific formatting but I am not sure how I am going to read this file to find every individual word without any punctuation.

I am guessing i am going to use a fscanf with a regex to do this but I am not 100% sure how to implement this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. There was no need to post such a long text.

Comment: I am sorry, but you show no effort. And no, this is not a case for a regex.

Comment: I love the **If you fin a mistake**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you bored? You read the text? ...

Comment: Also, regarding regular expressions [read this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). They are often more of a problem, than a solution. And certainly not applicable to your problem.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I skimmed the text up to that point. It is similar to skimming code: the eye catches things. BTW please post a proper link.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops ... I copied it and forgot to paste it

Comment: I think you would be more happy using `fgets` to read a line and using `strtok` to parse the words.

Comment: @pablo, wont i go over the buffer limit if i use fgets though with that setup? Also wont i just end up possibly like half ways through a word?

Comment: Depending on the size of the buffer, yes. But would would need to call `fgets` in a loop and check if a the read line has a newline. If it has not a newline, you can remember the last token returned by `strtok` and use the first token of the next iteration to put the word together.

Answer (score 1):

I said you should use `fgets` and `strtok`. You said in the comments

> wont i go over the buffer limit if i use fgets though with that setup? Also wont i just end up possibly like half ways through a word?

Well if you are using a POSIX system, you can use [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), this function
will read a line and properly allocate space for holding a whole line. If you
are not using a POSIX system where `getline` is not available, you can write a
wrapper of `fgets` that does that.

I've written such a wrapper and used in the past:

```
char *fgets_long(FILE *fp)
{
    size_t size = 0, currlen = 0;
    char line[1024];
    char *ret = NULL, *tmp;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        int wholeline = 0;
        size_t len = strlen(line);

        if(line[len - 1] == '\n')
        {
            line[len-- - 1] = 0;
            wholeline = 1;
        }

        if(currlen + len >= size)
        {
            // we need more space in the buffer
            size += (sizeof line) - (size ? 1 : 0);
            tmp = realloc(ret, size);
            if(tmp == NULL)
                break; // return all we've got so far
            ret = tmp;
        }

        memcpy(ret + currlen, line, len + 1);
        currlen += len;

        if(wholeline)
            break;
    }

    if(ret)
    {
        tmp = realloc(ret, currlen + 1);
        if(tmp)
            ret = tmp;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This function would give also the whole line and would allocate the memory for
it.

So the `geline` solution:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

// commong word delimiters
const char *delim = " \t.,-!\r\n";

while(getline(&line, &len, fp) > 0)
{
    char *word = strtok(line, delim);

    if(line == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "line has delimiters only, ignoring\n");
        continue;
    }

    do {
        do_your_calculations_with(word);
    } while((word = strtok(NULL, delim)));
}

free(line);
```

or the solution with my wrapper

```
char *line;
// commong word delimiters
const char *delim = " \t.,-!\r\n";
while((line = fgets_long(fp)))
{
    char *word = strtok(line, delim);

    if(line == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "line has delimiters only, ignoring\n");
        continue;
    }

    do {
        do_your_calculations_with(word);
    } while((word = strtok(NULL, delim)));

    free(line);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with POSIX. How do I know if i am running one of those systems

Comment: Linux,  BSD, Mac are [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) system, Windows is not.

Comment: Okay for const char *delim = " \t.,-!\r\n"; can you give me a run down on what \t.,-!\r\n checks for?

Comment: `strtok` splits the string when it encounters one of the characters in `delim`. In normal text words are separated by empty escapes, tabs, command, colons, exclamations, newlines, etc. I tried to put in there all common word separators. I've forgotten the semicolon, you can add that to the list.

Comment: How do i include parenthesis into that? just \\) and \\( ?

Comment: Like this: `char *delim = " \t.,-!;()[]{}\r\n"; `